# breakpoint in template for specific template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, template-specialization, conditional-breakpoint

What if i want to set breakpoint into constructor with condition if I == 10?

```
template < typename T, int I >
class C 
{
public:

    C<T, I>() { cout << I << endl; }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If conditional break point does not work try

```
template < typename T, int I >
class C 
{
public:

    C() 
    {
       if(I == 10)
       {
*         int a= 0; //or try __debugbreak();
       }
       cout << I << endl;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**
To break on specific class you may use `std::is_same<T, U>::value`(or boost analogue) in condition

Comment: What if we only want to break when this template is specialized for <class Foo, 10>? That is, is there any way to refer to the instantiating type T?

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. I'm assuming that would only work by changing the source itself rather than by some incantation in any of the breakpoint dialogs. I noticed the When Hit breakpoints can write out the template arguments, so there's maybe there's a glimmer of hope in being able to do this without changing code.